# How to write an excel formula to increase/decrease that cell value based on a value chosen from its dropdown list

Tags: excel-formula

Lets say A1 is a field that I want to keep a tally on.  I want to create a data validation list for cell A1 with 1 and -1.  Then I want a formula on A1 that says if I select 1, take whatever value is in A1 and add 1 to it.  If I select -1, take whatever value is in A1 and subtract 1.

For example, A1 has a value of 0 to start with.  I choose 1 from the drop down and cell A1 updates to 1.  I choose 1 again, cell A1 updates to 2.  I choose -1 and cell A1 updates to 1.

Doable?

I don't want to use the spin button because I have multiple fields in a small area that I need to replicate this for and the spin buttons won't work in a bunch of cells in close proximity.

Answer (score 0):

From a data architecture point of view, it is not advisable to do this, because you don't have an audit trail for the numbers displaying in your sheet.

Using only worksheet formulas, this is not possible, since a cell can only have either a constant value, or a formula, but not both.

To achieve the result described, you would need to involve VBA. A Worksheet_Change event that monitors changes in A1, then turns off events, performs the calculation and writes the result back into A1, then turns on events again.

But, again, if the cell is changed inadvertently, you have no way of tracking or checking how you arrived at the current number, so this approach is not advisable.